# What does it mean to type alias a structural type?

Tags: scala, type-alias, structural-typing

I came across something like this recently

```
object example {
   type DButil = AnyRef {
     val a: Int
     def b: String
   }
}
```

Things that confused me is that usage of `AnyRef` here, later I dig a bit more, and I find you can also do this:

```
object apple {}
object example {
   type DButil = apple.type {
     val a: Int
     def b: String
   }
}
```

I've never seen this pattern before, any insights and comments are appreciated.

Comment: Is a structural type. Basically `DButil` is anything that has an `a` field of type **Int**, and a method `b` that receives nothing a returns a **String**; in the second example, such type also has to be a subclass of `apple`. Those are, IMHO, a bad feature; structural types relay in reflection _(as such are insecure, slow, unsafe and less portable)_ and are not as flexible as they say they are. In my experience, they are used mostly by newcomers that come from languages like **Python** or **JS** and do not know how to properly model Polymorphism.

Comment: It's interesting that the 3rd edition of _Programming In Scala_ dropped the 2nd edition's discussion of structural subtyping beyond refinement typing.

Answer (score 1):

Type alias is just an additional name to the type.
The constructions like
AnyRef {
val a: Int
def b: String
}
apple.type {
val a: Int
def b: String
}
SomeSuperType {
val structuralMember1: Int
def structuralMember2: String
}

is Anonymous Class/Type that inherits superclass behavior and contains additional structural type parts that defined in braces.
And type alias is just a name for that Anonymous Type.